# hooks and contents: Part II

Tags: co.combinatorics, rt.representation-theory, symmetric-groups, partitions

This is a 2nd installment to [my earlier MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/263643/hooks-and-contents) for which Mark Wildon furnished a clean answer.

$\mathcal{O}(\pi)$ and $\mathcal{E}(\pi)$ stand for the number of odd and even cycles of a permutation $\pi$, respectively.

For a cell $\square$ in the Young diagram of a partition $\lambda$, let $h_{\square}$ and $c_{\square}$ denote the [hook length and content](http://www-math.mit.edu/~rstan/transparencies/hooks.pdf) of $\square$, respectively.

> **Question.** Is there a similar two-variable (generalized) formula to express
>   $$\frac1{n!}\sum_{\pi\in\mathfrak{S}_n}t^{\mathcal{O}(\pi)}q^{\mathcal{E}(\pi)}$$
>   in terms of hook-length $h_{\square}$ and contents $c_{\square}\,$?